# Reducing score in relation to countdown timer

Tags: actionscript-2

I have a quiz written in actionscript 2. Everything is going swimmingly except that I can't figure out how to get the score to reduce by one point for every second it takes to answer the question.

So... max score is 30 points for each question and there is a 30 sec timer... and so that the quiz is more challenging I'd like it to reduce by 1 point for every second it takes to answer.

Here is my code... and thanks in advance...

```
    Answer0Button.enabled=false; button0._visible=false;
Answer1Button.enabled=false; button1._visible=false;
Answer2Button.enabled=false; button2._visible=false;
Answer3Button.enabled=false; button3._visible=false;
Answer4Button.enabled=false; button4._visible=false;
Answer5Button.enabled=false; button5._visible=false;

function countdown() {
    counter--;
    countdown_txt.text = counter;
    if (counter == 0) {
        Answer0Button.enabled=false;
        Answer1Button.enabled=false;
        Answer2Button.enabled=false;
        Answer3Button.enabled=false;
        Answer4Button.enabled=false;
        Answer5Button.enabled=false;
        clearInterval(intID); 
        AnswerPopUp_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
        AnswerPopUp_mc.AnswerPopUp.DisplayResult.htmlText = "" + TimeIsUp + "";
    }
}

// defining variables for data
var ChosenNumberOfQuestions = int(0); // Number of questions in quiz
var TotalNumberOfQuestions = int(0); // Total number of questions in XML file
var NumberOfQuestions = int(0); // min of two above
var QuestionCounter = int(0); // for dynamicaly showing questions
var CurrentQuestion = QuestionCounter + 1; // for dynamicaly showing questions
var Points = 0; // for each question
var TotalPoints = 0; // Max Points
var Score = 0; // display total score
var NumberOfCorrectAnswers = 0; // counter for questions answered correctly

var RandOrderQuestions = new Array();
var Questions = new Array();
var Images = new Array();
var CorrectAnswers = new Array();
var Answers = new Array();
var ExplanationsIfCorrect = new Array();
var ExplanationsIfNotCorrect = new Array();
var TimesForSolving = new Array();
var NumberOfPoints = new Array();


// roll over states for buttons
button0.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    if (mouse_over_button0) { 
        _root.button0.nextFrame(); 
    } else { 
        _root.button0.prevFrame(); 
    } 
}; 
button1.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    if (mouse_over_button1) { 
        _root.button1.nextFrame(); 
    } else { 
        _root.button1.prevFrame(); 
    } 
}; 
button2.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    if (mouse_over_button2) { 
        _root.button2.nextFrame(); 
    } else { 
        _root.button2.prevFrame(); 
    } 
}; 
button3.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    if (mouse_over_button3) { 
        _root.button3.nextFrame(); 
    } else { 
        _root.button3.prevFrame(); 
    } 
}; 
button4.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    if (mouse_over_button4) { 
        _root.button4.nextFrame(); 
    } else { 
        _root.button4.prevFrame(); 
    } 
}; 
button5.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    if (mouse_over_button5) { 
        _root.button5.nextFrame(); 
    } else { 
        _root.button5.prevFrame(); 
    } 
}; 

// Label Color
var changeColor2 = new Color(label_mc.coloredLabel);
changeColor2.setRGB(labelColor);
// Change Buttons Color
var changeColorA = new Color(button0.letterA_mc.letterA);
changeColorA.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeColorB = new Color(button1.letterB_mc.letterB);
changeColorB.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeColorC = new Color(button2.letterC_mc.letterC);
changeColorC.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeColorD = new Color(button3.letterD_mc.letterD);
changeColorD.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeColorE = new Color(button4.letterE_mc.letterE);
changeColorE.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeColorF = new Color(button5.letterF_mc.letterF);
changeColorF.setRGB(labelColor);
// Change Color of points, counter...
var changeColorCounter = new Color(countdown_txt);
changeColorCounter.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeSlashColor = new Color(slash);
changeSlashColor.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeCurrQColor = new Color(DisplayCurrQ);
changeCurrQColor.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeTotalQColor = new Color(DisplayTotalQ);
changeTotalQColor.setRGB(labelColor);
var changePointsColor = new Color(DisplayPoints);
changePointsColor.setRGB(labelColor);
var changeScoreColor = new Color(DisplayScore);
changeScoreColor.setRGB(labelColor);

// Background Color
new Color (BackGround.bg).setRGB(BackgroundColor); 
new Color (FadeIn.bg1.bg).setRGB(BackgroundColor); 

// loading data from XML
var xmlData = new XML();
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;

xmlData.onLoad = function () {

    // Default Time for solving
    DefaultTimeInSeconds = this.firstChild.attributes.DefaultTimeInSeconds;
        trace ("DefaultTime: " + DefaultTimeInSeconds);
    // Default Points
    DefaultPoints = this.firstChild.attributes.DefaultPoints;
        trace ("DefaultPoints: " + DefaultPoints);
    // Default comment on answers
    DefaultIfCorrectAnswer = this.firstChild.attributes.DefaultIfCorrectAnswer;
    DefaultIfWrongAnswer = this.firstChild.attributes.DefaultIfWrongAnswer;

    // Default if time is up
    TimeIsUp = this.firstChild.attributes.TimeIsUp;

    // Random order of questions or not
    RandomQuestions = this.firstChild.attributes.RandomQuestions;
        trace ("RandomQuestions: " + RandomQuestions);

    // Number Of Questions 
    ChosenNumberOfQuestions = this.firstChild.attributes.NumberOfQuestions;
        trace ("ChosenNumberOfQuestions: " + ChosenNumberOfQuestions);

    // Counting  total number of Questions in XML file
    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
    for (var a=0; a<nodes.length; a++){
        TotalNumberOfQuestions = a+1;
    }  
    trace ("TotalNumberOfQuestions: " + TotalNumberOfQuestions);    

    // Finaly - number of questions in QUIZ - min of two above
    if (ChosenNumberOfQuestions < TotalNumberOfQuestions) { 
        NumberOfQuestions = ChosenNumberOfQuestions; 
    } else {
        NumberOfQuestions = TotalNumberOfQuestions;
    }

    // Random order Questions or not
    // first we populate array with question numbers
    for(i=0; i<TotalNumberOfQuestions; i++){
        RandOrderQuestions[i] = i;
        trace(RandOrderQuestions);
    }
    // if we want random questions we use random sorting of number of questions
    if (RandomQuestions == "TRUE") { 
        RandOrderQuestions.sort(function () {
            return random(2) ? true : false;
        });
        trace(RandOrderQuestions);
    } 
    ///////////////////////////
    // POPULATING FROM XML
    for (var i=0; i < NumberOfQuestions; i++ )
    {   
        // Chose the number of question from RandOrderQuestions array
        var numInXML = RandOrderQuestions[i];
        trace("Question number in XML: " + numInXML);

        // populating questions from XML
        Questions[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
        //trace(Questions);

        //populating Correct Answers from XML
        CorrectAnswers[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[1].attributes.correctAnswer; 
        //trace(CorrectAnswers);

        // populating options for answers from XML
        var NewArray = new Array(); // temp array for answers for each question
        for (var j=0; j < this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[1].childNodes.length; j++ )
            {
            trace(i + " "+ j);
            NewArray[j] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[1].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
            //trace(NewArray);
            NewArray.sort(function () {
            return random(2) ? true : false;
            });

            }
        Answers.push(NewArray); // push answers for this i question in main Answers array

        //populating additional options from XML
        ExplanationsIfCorrect[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[2].attributes.explanationIfCorrect; 
        ExplanationsIfNotCorrect[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[2].attributes.explanationIfNotCorrect; 
        TimesForSolving[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[2].attributes.timeInSeconds; 
        NumberOfPoints[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[2].attributes.points; 
        Images[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[2].attributes.imageIfCorrect; 
        Images[i] = this.firstChild.childNodes[numInXML].childNodes[2].attributes.imageIfIncorrect;

    }
    trace("Questions: " + Questions); trace("Correct Answers: " + CorrectAnswers); 
    trace(NewArray);
    trace(ExplanationsIfCorrect); trace(ExplanationsIfNotCorrect); trace(TimesForSolving); trace(NumberOfPoints);  trace(Images);

    // show first question (QuestionCounter=0)
    QuestionNumber.text = "Question #" + 1;
    QuestionDisplay.htmlText = Questions[QuestionCounter];  
    // show answers for first question (QuestionCounter=0)
    if (0 < Answers[QuestionCounter].length){ Answer0Display.text = Answers[QuestionCounter][0]; Answer0Button.enabled=true; button0._visible=true;} else { button0._visible=false;}
    if (1 < Answers[QuestionCounter].length){ Answer1Display.text = Answers[QuestionCounter][1]; Answer1Button.enabled=true; button1._visible=true;} else { button1._visible=false;}
    if (2 < Answers[QuestionCounter].length){ Answer2Display.text = Answers[QuestionCounter][2]; Answer2Button.enabled=true; button2._visible=true;} else { button2._visible=false;}
    if (3 < Answers[QuestionCounter].length){ Answer3Display.text = Answers[QuestionCounter][3]; Answer3Button.enabled=true; button3._visible=true;} else { button3._visible=false;}
    if (4 < Answers[QuestionCounter].length){ Answer4Display.text = Answers[QuestionCounter][4]; Answer4Button.enabled=true; button4._visible=true;} else { button4._visible=false;}
    if (5 < Answers[QuestionCounter].length){ Answer5Display.text = Answers[QuestionCounter][5]; Answer5Button.enabled=true; button5._visible=true;} else { button5._visible=false;}
    // show image if defined
    if (Images[QuestionCounter]){ loadMovie(Images[QuestionCounter],"imgContainer"); } else {  }
    // determine the number of points
    if (NumberOfPoints[QuestionCounter]){ Points = NumberOfPoints[QuestionCounter] } else { Points = DefaultPoints }

    // start counter
    if (TimesForSolving[QuestionCounter]){ 
        countdown_time = TimesForSolving[QuestionCounter] 
    } else { 
        countdown_time = DefaultTimeInSeconds 
    } // now call the function
        counter = countdown_time;
        countdown_txt.text = countdown_time;
        clearInterval(intID); 
        intID = setInterval(countdown,1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you added your scores, but I believe you can set score = counter since your counter is the time remaining.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The scores and questions are in an xml file. I have set the scores to be equal to when the timer starts but that doesn't reduce the scores.

Comment: The xml file is set out as follows... <quiz DefaultTimeInSeconds="30" DefaultPoints="30" NumberOfQuestions="10 " RandomQuestions="TRUE"

Comment: Set the scores to be equal to when the timer ends